# How can I query data from MongoDB in real-time?

Tags: python, mongodb

I created a MongoDB database, and I'm sending data to it. At the same time, I'm running a Python script to fetch data from that Database. I would like my script to print the new entry to my console as soon as it's pushed to the DB, but I don't know how to accomplish this.

This is my current work, but I don't like it because each time it will print the whole data on the db, even though I only want the last entry/entries as soon as they are updated:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import time
import random
from pprint import pprint

client = MongoClient(port=27017)

arr = []

db = client.one

mycol = client["coll"]



while True:
    cursor = db.mycol.find()
    for document in cursor:
        print(document['num'])
    time.sleep(2)
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to handle this, but the easiest might be to store an auto-incrementing "primaryKey" (or insert timestamp or whatever), and only print the results that occur after that key. Here is a quick example to demonstrate:

```
# we start at one...
highest_previous_primary_key = 1

while True:
    cursor = db.mycol.find()
    for document in cursor:

        # get the current primary key, and if it's greater than the previous one
        # we print the results and increment the variable to that value
        current_primary_key = document['primaryKey']
        if current_primary_key > highest_previous_primary_key:
            print(document['num'])
            highest_previous_primary_key = current_primary_key

    time.sleep(2)
```

This is perhaps the laziest approach to do. But beyond this, you may try doing:

1. Adjusting the query itself, so it only gets items > the primaryKey (imagine if you had a billion results and each time you fetched all results).

Comment: Hey, i'm making some more testing and the problem is that sometimes it stops printing the new entries, just like the loop is broken for some reason, do you have any idea why?

Comment: Exactly after the record number 4 it will stop running

Answer (score 5):

Mongo DB since version 3.6 supports a feature call "Change Streams". In the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) you will find this simple Python example among some others:

```
cursor = db.inventory.watch()
document = next(cursor)
```

If `next()` is supported on the cursor your should also be able to use it in loops, generators and even `asyncio`.

Comment: Yes, i know about Change Streams and i think it would be the best way to do that, but i tried to use it and i got that i can only use it for a replica db, and my db is not a replica